# How to Publish Quarto HTML book in Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, quarto

I rendered a Quarto HTML book with several pages and trying to host the Quarto HTML book in Microsoft sharepoint / Teams. But clueless on how to publish it in Microsoft sharepoint. Because the requirements for Sharepoint is .aspx and Quarto files are in html. Manually changing the HTML to aspx is not a viable solution. Is there anyway to upload & publish Quarto HTML pages to Sharepoint?